# Google Apps Email Audit API with 2 Legged OAuth

Tags: google-api-client

I'm currently trying to use the GData .net API

Here is the documentation I'm using http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/audit/docs/1.0/audit_developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_all_mailbox_status

What I'm trying to do is to use 2 legged authentication to do this example

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Apps;
using Google.GData.Extensions.Apps;
...

MailMonitor monitor = new MailMonitor();
monitor.BeginDate = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15);
monitor.EndDate = new DateTime(2009, 6, 30, 23, 20, 0);
monitor.IncomingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
monitor.OutgoingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.HEADER_ONLY;
monitor.DraftMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
monitor.ChatMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE;
monitor.DestinationUserName = "namrata";

AuditService service = new AuditService("example.com", "example.com-auditapp-v1");
service.setUserCredentials("admin@example.com", "p@55w0rd");
MailMonitor monitorEntry = service.CreateMailMonitor("abhishek", monitor);
```

I've gotten as far as

```
var monitor = new MailMonitor
            {
                EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                IncomingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE,
                OutgoingEmailMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.HEADER_ONLY,
                DraftMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE,
                ChatMonitorLevel = MonitorLevel.FULL_MESSAGE,
                DestinationUserName = "MYUSER"
            };
            var service = new AuditService("MYDOMAIN", "MYDOMAIN-auditapp-v1");
            var requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("auditapi", "MYDOMAIN-auditapp-v1")
                                     {
                                         ConsumerKey = "MYDOMAIN", 
                                        ConsumerSecret = "MYKEY"
                                     };
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
            var monitorEntry = service.CreateMailMonitor("MYUSER", monitor);
```

This is trying to setup a monitor for any emails coming or going for one day. The response is Unknown authorization header (Error 401).

I got the key from following this guide http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins.html

I've no idea how to debug this, I can't find an example of 2 legged auth with the Email Audit API and I can't use wireshark because this is encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 0):

What key did you use?
Remember API key is not the same as Consumer Secret. Consumer Secret is something which is unique to your domain.

You can find your consumer secret by going to your domain's Cpanel -> Advanced Settings -> Manage OAuth Domain Key. This is the secret your domain and Google share.
[Here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162105) is a doc for your reference.

Comment: If you read the question I explain where I got the key. The same place you just suggested.